# Typing in vietnamese characters saves another characters

Tags: android, webview, special-characters

I am using this WebView with a form. It saves the data (via PHP&MySQL) I typed using my tablet. I am typing in Vietnamese characters (see yellow label # 1), but when I hit the save (reply) button, a different characters were saved (see yellow label # 2)...

[image]

..when I typed a message (viet) using my PC, and saving it, the characters were displayed fine both in PC and android tablet...

Any ideas what could be the problem? Thanks in Advanced!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use unicode encoding when typing Vietnamese
Please [type Vietnamese](https://vietnamesetyping.com/) Online here and copy paste